# [Wordpress + PHP + MySQL]Database SELECT query inside plugin returns no result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I'm attempting to to retrieve records from a select query inside a plugin, but no records are being returned, and I am receiving the following error message (web console). My question is, what am I overlooking here?:

```html
Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: .ajax/w.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/w.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/w.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/w.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/w.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/w.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 12 more… } getregions.js:47:17
error getregions.js:48:17
Internal Server Error getregions.js:49:17
```

My php code reads as follows:

```html
function getregions_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'getregions-script',
    plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "assets/getregions.js",
    array('jquery'),
    '1.0',
    true
  );

  wp_localize_script(
    'getregions-script', // this needs to match the name of our enqueued script
    'gymRegions',      // the name of the object
    array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')) // the property/value
  );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'getregions_scripts' );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_showcountries', 'showcountries_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_no_priv_showcountries', 'showcountries_callback' );
```

```html
function showcountries_callback() {

  $mydb = new wpdb('user','password','db','localhost');
  $mydb->show_errors();

  $makeselection=$_POST["makeselection"];

  if($makeselection=="getCountryList"){
          //$showcountry = pdo_query("Select distinct wp_usermeta.meta_value, COUNTRY_MAPPING.COUNTRY_NAME from wp_usermeta, COUNTRY_MAPPING where wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'country_registration' and wp_usermeta.meta_value = COUNTRY_MAPPING.COUNTRY_CODE");
     $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "usermeta";
     $sql = $wpdb->prepare("Select distinct meta_value, COUNTRY_MAPPING.COUNTRY_NAME
                               from {$table_name}, COUNTRY_MAPPING
                               where meta_key = 'country_registration'
                               and meta_value = COUNTRY_MAPPING.COUNTRY_CODE");
     $showcountry = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);

     if (!$showcountry) {
         //$message  = 'Invalid query: ' . pdo_error() . "\n";
         //$message .= 'Whole query: ' . $showcountry;
         //die($message);
     }else{
         $html = "<option value=''>Select Country</option>";
         foreach($showcountry as $row){
            $html .= "<option value='{$row->meta_value}'>{$row->COUNTRY_NAME}</option>";
         }
         echo json_encode($html, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
     }
   }
   wp_die();
 }
```

My javascript (getregions.js) file reads as follows:

```html
function feedData($) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var serialized = $('#MyForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: gymRegions.ajaxurl,
            data:{action: "showcountries", makeselection: "getCountryList", serialized}, 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, status, error) {
                $('#CountryList').append(data);
            },
            error: function (data, status, error) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

My .htaccess file reads as:

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: first mistake you are not returning a json, your function is returning html
tip: you don`t have to create another connection to db, simple use "global $wpdb"

Comment: Done, as in just referencing `global $wpdb`. But still my original issues remains. Any further suggestions?

Comment: change your javascript 
dataType : "html",
beacuse your php code is throwing html 
and in php code instead of echo json_encode($html, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
only write echo $html;

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `dataType` to "html" and remove your call to `json_encode` -- simply echo the HTML out. It doesn't seem like you want to actually receive JSON data.

---

If you do actually want to receive JSON data, you need to wrap your HTML into an array, then run it through `json_encode`:

```
echo json_encode( array( 'html' => $html ) );
```

Then in your JavaScript you'd access the HTML through the object:

```
success: function (data, status, error) {
    $('#CountryList').append(data.html);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I implemented `json_encode( array( 'html' => $html ) )` as you mentioned, but still the error persists. What should I do next? How would I check for a record count, just to ascertain whether any records are actually being returned?

Comment: Use your browser debugger, and the Network tab (filter for XHR), to inspect the ajax request and response. You can preview the response as if you were browsing to it normally too, which might give you a better error message. Also, make sure that `WP_DEBUG` is set to true in your `wp-config.php` file.

Comment: I'm getting a status code: 500 Internal Server Error, on Method Post to File admin-ajax.php. Any idea what could be happening here?

Comment: Did you enable `WP_DEBUG`?

Comment: Yes, I've enabled it. But no output to the screen is being displayed.

Comment: It might be an issue in `.htaccess` but that seems unlikely since the rest of your site apparently works. Might want to add that in your question anyway since it helps inform us. Also, can you add in your action hooks too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113186/discussion-between-the-maniac-and-theog).

Comment: Ok, so I've added in my action hooks to the top of my question.